# How to get the get the select values created by ACF plugin in wordpress

Tags: plugins, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

Basically I want to display the select box so admin can select the option while creating or editing a category to display the category in front page with image or not.

I use advanced custom plugin to add a select box in categories page.
I created a custom field group of display with

```
field label  :  Select to display  
field name :   select_to_display_  
field type :   Select  
options :   no,yes
```

location rules :  Taxonomy term add/edit equal to categories.

As soon as I create the custom field the values are stored in db of `wp_postmeta` table as

```
meta_key:field key value
meta_value:a:12:{s:3:"key";s:19:"field_51d53f2ed1236";s:5:"label";s:17:"Select to display";s:4:"name";s:18:"select_to_display_";s:4:"type";s:6:"select";s:12:"instructions";s:0:"";s:8:"required";s:1:"0";s:7:"choices";a:2:{s:2:"NO";s:2:"NO";s:3:"YES";s:3:"YES";}s:13:"default_value";s:0:"";s:10:"allow_null";s:1:"0";s:8:"multiple";s:1:"0";s:17:"conditional_logic";a:3:{s:6:"status";s:1:"0";s:5:"rules";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:5:"field";s:19:"field_51d53f2ed1236";s:8:"operator";s:2:"==";s:5:"value";s:2:"NO";}}s:8:"allorany";s:3:"all";}s:8:"order_no";i:0;}
```

When I go to dashboard->post->categories I can display the select box with options but when I select any option and click on update it is updating.

but when in `index.php`

```
echo  get_field(' select_to_display_'); //nothing is displaying here

$field = get_field_object('field_51d3f9c3f5554');

if($field['choices'] == 'false') 
    {
        echo 'A value is  set';
     } else 
    {

    echo 'A value is not set';
    }
```

I'm always getting value is not set. I don't know whether my selected values are saving db or not. I don't have any meta key or values like `wp_acf` in database.

But once you select the dropdown as `yes` in category page it is saving even after page refresh the value is `yes`.

I'm getting confused whether the value is saving to db or not.

Comment: Please link to specific plugin when asking about one, so that others don't have to guess and spend time looking it up.

Answer (score 1):

In this bit of code:

```
$field = get_field_object('field_51d3f9c3f5554');
```

`$field['choices']` will contain an array of the available choices for that field, not the currently selected value, `$field['value']` contains the currently selected value.

However, using `get_field_object` when all you want is the currently selected value is unnecessary.

for the correct use of `get_field()`, [read the documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/) carefully to learn what you must pass to that function, specifically the `$post_id examples` section. taxonomy terms are not the same as posts, you have to pass an additional argument in the form of `"$taxonomy_$term_id"`.

EDIT- also note, in your call to `get_field(' select_to_display_')`, you have a space before the key name, which will fail unless the key is actually prefixed with a space, which I presume is not the case.

Comment: Thank you milo but i tried even iam not able to get the selected value $field=get_field('select_to_display_',$category_id);
echo $field;//nothing is displaying
echo $field['value'];//nothing is displaying

Comment: plaese help with this iam really stucking from 3 days for simply getting the selected values

Comment: you need to pass literally the text `category_`, then the ID of the category appended to the end.